# How does Bash handle variables in memory?

Tags: linux, bash, memory, process

I just challenged myself to find and change a value in memory using **[scanmem](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scanmem)** and wrote this script to increment a simple value every 5 seconds.

```
  #!/bin/bash

  i=88 #start counting from..
  printf "Variable increments every 5s\n"
  while [ 1 ]
  do 
    printf "Variable is %d\n" $i
    sleep 5s
    if [ $i -eq 300 ]; then 
            printf "Variable is now 300! WELL DONE!!\n"
            exit 1
    else
            i=$(( $i + 1))

            if [ $i -gt 299 ]; then
                    printf "Time is up!\n"
                    exit 0
            fi
    fi
  done
```

Crappy scripting aside (I'm betting it's that causing me trouble though!); I can find the value (always 4 results) in 2 scans in **scanmem** attached to the PID (from **ps ax | grep bash**) but the variable refuses to SET to 300. I confirmed they're correct using UPDATE and LIST. It will actually SET but always returns to the next increment.

So why does the value refuse to be changed?
script is run as user, scanmem is sudoed